# Batch tracking in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a CSV that contains some production data. When loaded into Excels power query it has a structure similar to this (material batches may contain remainders of old material batches as recycling material):

```
Mat_Batch    Date         Recyc_Batch    RawMaterial1    RawMaterial2    RawMaterial3    Amount1    Amount2    Amount3
123          01.11.2019                  Fe              Cr              Ni              70         19         11
234          01.12.2019                  Fe              Cr              Ni              71         18         11
345          01.02.2020   123            Fe              Cr              Ni              72         17          9
456          01.01.2020   234            Fe              Cr              Ni              70         19         11
567          01.02.2020                  Fe              Cr              Ni              72         16         10
678          01.01.2020   456            Fe              Cr              Ni              70         19         11
```

Another CSV has the following content (it simply links a production batch to a material batch; production batches may contain more than one material batch):

```
Batch    Mat_Batch
abc      456
abc      567
bcd      345
```

Now I would like to use power query m to evaluate which material batches exactly were used to produce a part batch. E.g. batch "abc" was made from 456 + 567 + 234 (as recycling material in 456).

As a first step, I filter the production batch table by a specific batch and join both tables via the resulting Mat_Batch column. As a second iteration I seperate the Recyc_Batch column from the matched material batches and do a second join with a copy of my material batch table to gain all additional recycling materials that where used. But how could I do so "infinite" times? The way I'm doing it I have to create additional queries for each iteration but I need a way to automatically repeat those joining steps until there is no more additional recycling material used.

Answer (score 0):

here is a Query (Result) you can use (if I understood correct)

```
let
    Quelle = Table.NestedJoin(tbl_Material, {"Mat_Batch"}, tbl_Production, {"Mat_Batch"}, "tbl_Production", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    Combine_Sources = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Quelle, "tbl_Production", {"Batch"}, {"Batch"}),
    DeleteOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Combine_Sources,{"Batch", "Mat_Batch", "Recyc_Batch"}),
    UnpivotOtherColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(DeleteOtherColumns, {"Batch"}, "Attribut", "Wert"),
    FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(UnpivotOtherColumns, each ([Batch] <> null)),
    SortRows = Table.Sort(FilterRows,{{"Batch", Order.Ascending}})
in
    SortRows
```

The result looks like that
[image: PowerQuery Result]
Best regards Chris